# Set value of a variable that is stored in an array?

Tags: powershell

I have a few variables which I have stored in an array. Is it possible to null check them and if it is null change the value to "None" using a ForEach Loop?

```
$a = ""
$b = ""
$c = "something"

$array = @($a, $b, $c)

ForEach($element in $array){
   If(!$element){
     Set-Variable -Name $element -Value "None"
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, but do you want to replace `$null` or empty strings? Your array has no null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will recreate the `$array`. Watch out for the difference in empty string `""` and `$null`

```
$a = $null
$b = ""
$c = "something"

$array = @($a, $b, $c)

$array = ForEach($element in $array){
    If($element -eq $null){
        "none"
    }else{
        $element
    }
}
$array
```

If you want to cover both `$null` and `""` you may check it with `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($element)` as LotPings pointed out:

```
if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($element)){
    "none"
}else{
    $element
}
```

However if you want to process nested arrays, things get a little bit complicated since powershell has problems to return single element arrays (here is a nice little article about it: [Powershell Functions do not return single element arrays](https://blog.tyang.org/2011/02/24/powershell-functions-do-not-return-single-element-arrays/))
As the article states you need an extra comma infront of your single element array. That would look like this:

```
$a = @()
$b = @()
$c = @("something")

$array = @($a,$b,$c)

$array = ForEach ($element in $array){ 
    if ($element.count -eq 0){
         ,@("none")
    }else{
         ,$element
    }
}
$array
$array | ForEach-Object {$_.gettype()}
```

Comment: Side question. If it was $a = @(), $b = @() and $c = @("something") would you be able to add "none" to the empty arrays? like If($element.count -eq 0){$element += "None"}?

Comment: Just a hint for OP, if you want to check both `if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($element)){"none"}else{$element}`

Comment: @T-Me quite interesting. I really appreciate the help!